# Annotations in xml convert to json?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

Im using **MASK RCNN** keras and tensorflow and I would like to know if someone has been able to train using a xml annotation file, or if someone has converted xml to json.
Can someone show me an example how to use the load_() function if I change my xml file to json?

I made some annotations with VIA tool and it was correct,(train and detection) but I would really like to use the xml annotations because are done and it takes a long time to start over.

I have converted my xml files to json, but I don't have polygons or regions in my annotations, how could I use it? 
thank you.

I would appreciate it.

```
annotations1 = json.load(open(os.path.join(dataset_dir, "dataset.json")))

        annotations = list(annotations1.values())  # don't need the dict keys

        annotations = [a for a in annotations if a['images']]

        for a in annotations:

            polygons = [r['shape_attributes'] for r in a['regions'].values()]

            image_path = os.path.join(dataset_dir, a['filename'])
            image = skimage.io.imread(image_path)
            height, width = image.shape[:2]

            self.add_image(
                "damage",  
                image_id=a['filename'],  
                path=image_path,
                width=width, height=height,
                polygons=polygons)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own script to convert from XML to JSON, or simply delete the `load_mask()` function.

Comment: Thanks, that was i did, i have created my own script to convert from xml to json, and also i had to create the points beetween the rectangle area because you need polygon shape.